# How shall I use fakesAync in Angular unit test when you make an HTTP call that returns an observable?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous

I'm trying to get class-name of a HTML element that changes just after I click on it, and since the click fires a HTTP call to the server and after the data has been fetched then class-name change it back.

```
# HTML
<div class="class-name" (click)="fetchData()" [ngClass]="{'class-name--loading': dataFetching}">folder name</div>

#TS file
fetchData() {
  this.dataFetching = true;
  this.storageService.ls()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.dataFetching = false;
    ...
  })
}

# TEST
it('if the folder icon on /NAME is clicked, we should load the content from the server', fakeAsync(() => {
   const firstFolder = nativeEl.querySelectorAll('.storage')[0].querySelectorAll('.storage__folder__name')[0];

   storageService.ls.and.returnValue(of({
     name: 'name folder',
     complete: true,
   }));

   firstFolder.querySelector('i').click();
   fixture.detectChanges();

   expect(correvateFirstFolder.getAttribute('class').includes('--loading')).toBeTruthy();
   tick();
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(correvateFirstFolder.getAttribute('class').includes('--loading')).toBeFalsy();
}));
```

it fails on the first expect, and if I log the class name, I can't see it changing, it's always the original.

Comment: Could you please show a bit more like the component and the corresponding template?

Comment: No need for `fakeAsync` or `tick`. Just spy on the service method and return the result mock wrapped in an `Observable`.

Comment: The Head Rush, it's what I'm doing, but doesn't give the time to test the class-name changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your service is stubbed within the test.

It looks like the service emits immediately, that's why once you wait with `tick()` and run `detectChanges()` the loading value will be already changed to true.

So what I would do, is, I would mock the service call with a `Subject` and then have a test case along those lines (beaware this is pseudo code)

```
it('if the folder icon on /NAME is clicked, we should load the content from the server', fakeAsync(() => {

   const fsSubject = new Subject();
   storageService.ls.and.returnValue(fsSubject.asObservable());

   const firstFolder = nativeEl.querySelectorAll('.storage')[0].querySelectorAll('.storage__folder__name')[0];

   firstFolder.querySelector('i').click();
   fixture.detectChanges();

   tick();
   detectChanges();

   expect(correvateFirstFolder.getAttribute('class').includes('--loading')).toBeTruthy();
  
   // emit the value here after your check
   fsSubject.next({
     name: 'name folder',
     complete: true,
   });

   tick();
   detectChanges();

   expect(correvateFirstFolder.getAttribute('class').includes('--loading')).toBeFalsy();
}));
```

Comment: Fantastic it worked.
I didn't know I had to return Subject from which to emit the expected value afterwards, thanks a lot.

Comment: well you only need a subject if you want the observable under test to emit at a specific time. in other cases your setup would be fine.

Comment: Yes I got that, bu then I'll test that HTML changed based on the fetched data as well ;)